# How I can write string for default value with fluent api in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-fluent-api

```sql
builder.Property(a => a.ImagePath).HasDefaultValue("Difualt.png");
```

The dataType of ImagePath is varchar(180),
The code above throws this error:

> The name "Defulat.png" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

I want if a user didn't put self-image, I have the default image for the show.

Comment: Just an aside ... Difualt.png or Defulat.png or ( I suspect) Default.png  ?

Comment: Do your String constants look like typos?, e.g. "Difualt.png" vs "Defulat.png" vs. "Default.png"

Comment: Did you try using `.HasDefaultValueSql("Default.png");`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is, that you are specifying an `int` field but your are sending a `string` value. As you are not specifying a "HasColumnType" value, an `int` is implied.

Changing your code to something like this should work:

```
builder.Property(a => a.ImagePath).HasColumnType("varchar(255)").HasDefaultValue("Difualt.png");
```